# Swarm healthcheck sets task to complete state

Tags: node.js, docker, swarm

A have created a swarm and running a simple nodejs app on it. I would have liked to test how the healthcheck works in swarm environment. I have set the healthcheck block int the compose file like this:

```
 healthcheck:
        test:  ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:3000/healthcheck"]
        interval: 1m
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 1
        start_period: 20s
```

The nodejs source is simple:

```
const express = require("express");
const os = require("os");

var fs = require('fs');
const app=express();
let health = "ok";

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    var hostname = fs.readFileSync('/host/etc/hostname', 'utf8');

    var body =    " Hello from SwarmDemo (V1.0)" + "<br>";
    body = body + " container name: " + os.hostname()+ "<br>";
    body = body + " host name: " + hostname;

    res.send(body);
});

app.get("/healthcheck", (req, res) => {
    if (health == "ok") {
        res.send("OK")
    } else {
        res.status(503);
        res.send("");
    }
});

app.get("/kill", (req, res) => {
    var hostname = fs.readFileSync('/host/etc/hostname', 'utf8');

    health = "killed";
    res.send("Host " + hostname + " was killed!")
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

I expected swarm to stop the unhealthy container and start a new one, but it doesn't. It stops the container, but it only sets the task state to complete and leave it, doesn't start a new one.

If I inspect the stopped container, it says that the exitCode is 0, which means, as far as I know, it was stopped successfully, bu not because of a failure. I can see the healthchek call, which returned 503 HTTP response code too:

```
        "State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2019-08-16T17:33:55.778937745Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2019-08-16T17:35:59.664281868Z",
            "Health": {
                "Status": "unhealthy",
                "FailingStreak": 1,
                "Log": [
                    {
                        "Start": "2019-08-16T19:34:55.779656075+02:00",
                        "End": "2019-08-16T19:34:56.648373763+02:00",
                        "ExitCode": 0,
                        "Output": "  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\r100     2  100     2    0     0     22      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    22\nOK"
                    },
                    {
                        "Start": "2019-08-16T19:35:56.658734507+02:00",
                        "End": "2019-08-16T19:35:57.549464299+02:00",
                        "ExitCode": 22,
                        "Output": "  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0\ncurl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 503 Service Unavailable\n"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

If I modify the restart policy from on-failure to any:

```
            restart_policy:
                condition: any
                delay: 5s
                max_attempts: 3
                window: 30s
```

it works. It stops the contaier and starts a new one.

My question is: How could I force the swarm to start a new container when the health check fails. Should I send back something else then 5xx HTTP response code?

I have seen articles, where the HTTP call was wrapped in a script. If the HTTP call returned anything else then 200, it returned 1, otherwise it returned 0.

Would it be the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, if the docker stops the container without problem, the status will be a complete. Which means, that it doesn't care about the health status in this case.

If I stop the node process in the kill method:

```
app.get("/kill", (req, res) => {
 process.exit(1);
});
```

or in the healthcheck:

```
app.get("/healthcheck", (req, res) => {
    if (health == "ok") {
        res.send("OK")
    } else {
        process.exit(1);
    }
});
```

it works. The status will be failed.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to cause a `1` exit code may be with the following health check test:

```
test: curl --fail http://localhost || exit 1
```